# Elastic stack, how should I send my custom python logs

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

So I have some custom logging in python which comes in from multiple processes to log a certain crash with a format like

```
{timestamp},{PID},{Cause}
```

Now I want these events to be sent to logstash and be used in ELK to later see some info on my kibana dashboard. I've never used ELK before so my question is, what would be the best approach?

-Use python-logstash and have 2 loggers at once

-Simply send the array to logstash( HTTP i think? ) at the time it gets logged and use dissect later?

-Make a JSON when the logger is logging the line and send that to logstash?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send only the crash, then having a separate logger is handy.

```
logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1)
```

and configure the logstash pipeline for tcp input.

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5959
    }
}


filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

for sending json like data, populate a dict in python and send then using the logger with *extra* parameter.

`logger.log(level=logging.WARN, msg="process crashed", extra={'PID':pid, 'Cause': cause})`

result records will look like

`{
  PID:321,
  Cause:'abcde',
  timestamp:"2019-12-10T13:37:51.906Z",
  message:"process crashed"
}`